# recyclerView.adapter on notifydatasetchanged hangs the ui android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am having trouble with updating my recyclerview with notify data set changed, since it hangs the ui for a couple of seconds upon called.
After searching on the net, it was suggested to update the adapter on the background thread.

```
 private synchronized void updateAdapter() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return null;
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

And upon running this line of code, the app crashed with the error,

"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

And upon searching further, it was suggested that the solution was to run on the ui thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {

}
});
```

Which brings me back to my initial problem.
How should i handle this problem? Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: You can't do `notifyDataSetChanged` in  `doInBackground`, you have to do it inside `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute . 
cause `doInBackground` just a callback fired in worker thread , and you would like to do `notifyDataSetChanged` which has to be in UI thread , so you can do `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onProgressUpdate` which work as handler to transfer your massage from worker thread to UI thread ,  or `onPostExecute which called in your UI thread after the worker thread finishes its work .

Comment: But that hangs the ui. thats the initial problem.

Comment: This just proves that people mark question as duplicate without even reading it, so much for the community.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private synchronized void updateAdapter() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return null;
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

Please study [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) `doInBackground` should not have any UI changes .In this case u are performing UI changes on seperate thread in asynctask . Put your notifydatasetchanged on onPostExecute as shown below( which works on Main Thread ). To add `onPreExcute()` and `onPostExecute()` are performed on Main UI and `onBackground()` on separate thread ( not Main UI ).

```
 private synchronized void updateAdapter() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           // query your db or perform long operations here 
           return null;
        }

        @Override
        onPostExecute(Void.. params){
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: onPostExeceute runs in the UI thread and it will hang the UI also

Comment: onRunning onPostExecute it hangs the ui which is the initial problem.

Comment: use notifychanged( int position ) this would help you update only specific cells.Please share your code because there shouldnt be too laggy until unless you are using a large number of  different views

Comment: I have the sam eproblem that you was facing. did you find the solution yet?

Comment: Hi @ShockWave... Please share the code... AsyncTask should suffice the problem ...

Comment: hello @DRYBeliever , my code is too complex, as i am using volley to request data, it is already getting data from asynctask, and i amm getting all the data on my ui thread , now its a large amount of data, which is causing sticky UI. i tried many possibilities, and i have designed rest services, so for code, i have to send you many many files